# XML Node Reordering with C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

My program has a listbox which allows users select the order of the "CaseName" nodes. The listbox has the following items in the shown order,

```
"Normal Cold Start"
"Normal Warm Start"
"Normal Very Hot Start"
```

The following XML file corresponds to the above list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DsCyclicLoading xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DsCyclicLoading.xsd">
  <CyclicLoading>
    <ComponentID>1</ComponentID>
    <ComponentName>ABC</ComponentName>
    <Standard>123</Standard>
    <CaseName>Normal Cold Start</CaseName>
  </CyclicLoading>
  <CyclicLoading>
    <ComponentID>2</ComponentID>
    <ComponentName>DEF</ComponentName>
    <Standard>456</Standard>
    <CaseName>Normal Warm Start</CaseName>
  </CyclicLoading>
  <CyclicLoading>
    <ComponentID>3</ComponentID>
    <ComponentName>GHI</ComponentName>
    <Standard>789</Standard>
    <CaseName>Normal Very Hot Start</CaseName>
  </CyclicLoading>
</DsCyclicLoading>
```

I'd like to change the XML file to reflect the following new order:

```
"Normal Very Hot Start"
"Normal Cold Start"
"Normal Warm Start"
```

So, the new XML file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DsCyclicLoading xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DsCyclicLoading.xsd">
  <CyclicLoading>
    <ComponentID>3</ComponentID>
    <ComponentName>GHI</ComponentName>
    <Standard>789</Standard>
    <CaseName>Normal Very Hot Start</CaseName>
  </CyclicLoading>
  <CyclicLoading>
    <ComponentID>1</ComponentID>
    <ComponentName>ABC</ComponentName>
    <Standard>123</Standard>
    <CaseName>Normal Cold Start</CaseName>
  </CyclicLoading>
  <CyclicLoading>
    <ComponentID>2</ComponentID>
    <ComponentName>DEF</ComponentName>
    <Standard>456</Standard>
    <CaseName>Normal Warm Start</CaseName>
  </CyclicLoading>
</DsCyclicLoading>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You open the file in an editor like Notepad++ and change it. What exactly is the question/problem? Please read [ask] and [edit] your post to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: I'd like to do this programmatically with C# code. The XML is the datasource of a bindingnavigator control and the order of the nodes is important.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your C# code, where you try to change the order of the XML elements in the XML code. While editing your question you might want to add the `C#` tag to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have VB.NET code that does the job, but I cannot convert it to C#. I don't know if it would be proper to ask for help for conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var xd = XDocument.Parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""yes""?>
<DsCyclicLoading xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/DsCyclicLoading.xsd"">
    <CyclicLoading>
        <ComponentID>1</ComponentID>
        <ComponentName>ABC</ComponentName>
        <Standard>123</Standard>
        <CaseName>Normal Cold Start</CaseName>
    </CyclicLoading>
    <CyclicLoading>
        <ComponentID>2</ComponentID>
        <ComponentName>DEF</ComponentName>
        <Standard>456</Standard>
        <CaseName>Normal Warm Start</CaseName>
    </CyclicLoading>
    <CyclicLoading>
        <ComponentID>3</ComponentID>
        <ComponentName>GHI</ComponentName>
        <Standard>789</Standard>
        <CaseName>Normal Very Hot Start</CaseName>
    </CyclicLoading>
</DsCyclicLoading>");

var predefined = new[]
{
    "Normal Very Hot Start",
    "Normal Cold Start",
    "Normal Warm Start",
}
    .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.x, x => x.n);

var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://tempuri.org/DsCyclicLoading.xsd");

var nodes = xd.Root.Elements().OrderBy(x => predefined[x.Element(ns + "CaseName").Value]).ToArray();

xd.Root.ReplaceNodes(nodes);
```

This gives:

```
<DsCyclicLoading xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DsCyclicLoading.xsd">
  <CyclicLoading>
    <ComponentID>3</ComponentID>
    <ComponentName>GHI</ComponentName>
    <Standard>789</Standard>
    <CaseName>Normal Very Hot Start</CaseName>
  </CyclicLoading>
  <CyclicLoading>
    <ComponentID>1</ComponentID>
    <ComponentName>ABC</ComponentName>
    <Standard>123</Standard>
    <CaseName>Normal Cold Start</CaseName>
  </CyclicLoading>
  <CyclicLoading>
    <ComponentID>2</ComponentID>
    <ComponentName>DEF</ComponentName>
    <Standard>456</Standard>
    <CaseName>Normal Warm Start</CaseName>
  </CyclicLoading>
</DsCyclicLoading>
```

Comment: Dear Enigmativity, This is a wonderful solution and it works. I have one question. If I already have a string array itemsArray populated with the listbox items, how can I use that instead of the predefined array?
I can do the following of course:
           var predefined = new[]
            {
                itemsArray[0],
                itemsArray[1],
                itemsArray[2],
            }
But since itemsArray is also a dynamic array, I cannot hard code itemsArray[0],itemsArray[1],...
I tried using Array.Copy, but I don't know if I can use that within array description block.

Comment: Just use `itemsArray` as it is.

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity.